# Index was outside the bounds of the array in vb.net while reading a text file

Tags: vb.net

I have a piece of text that has a list of Oscar movies from 1928 - 2014. I'm using an array to find the name of the film and place it into one textbox and the genre in the next. The genre is next to the movies name. I'm trying to access the two separately and place it into two different textboxes.

My Code:

```
Dim mvs(86) As Movie

Private Sub FrmAcademy_Load() Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim mviLine As String
    Dim mviData(1) As String
    Dim allMovies() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Oscars.txt")

    For mviList As Integer = 0 To 86
        mviLine = allMovies(mviList)
        mviData = mviLine.Split(","c)
        mvs(mviList).mviName = mviData(0)
        mvs(mviList).gnrName = mviData(1)

        Dim mviYear As Integer = 0
        Dim mviIndex As Integer = 0

        If (IsNumeric(txtAwards.Text)) = True Then
            mviYear = CInt(txtAwards.Text)
        End If

        If (mviYear >= 1928) Or (mviYear <= 2014) Then
            mviIndex = 1928 - mviYear
            txtFilm.Text = mvs(mviIndex).mviName
            txtGenre.Text = mvs(mviIndex).mviName
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub btnPicture_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPicture.Click
    If (IsNumeric(txtAwards.Text)) = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a year as a numeric value")
    ElseIf CInt(txtAwards.Text) > 2014 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please choose a year in range")
    ElseIf CInt(txtAwards.Text) < 1928 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please choose a year in range")
    End If
```

Comment: What line was the exception thrown on? What was the index and what were the valid bounds? If you look at the actual data in use when the exception occurred, the issue should be obvious. You are presumably assuming that you're going to split a line into two parts on a comma when there's no comma in the line but you don't need us to tell you that because you have the data right in front of you when the exception occurs. You just have to look at it.

Comment: it was mvs(mviIndex).mviName

Comment: This line: `mviIndex = 1928 - mviYear` What if the year of the movie is 2005? It will produce -77 which is of course an invalid value for an array index.

Comment: I tried to use an if statement to suppress that

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it supposed to be:

```
If (mviYear >= 1928) And (mviYear <= 2014) Then
    mviIndex = mviYear - 1928
```

Answer (score 0):

To get better help, at least take the time to format your code properly.

Your `mvs` array is declared, but where is each element initialized?

On the first line of your `For` loop, add this code:  `mvs(mviList) = New Movie()`